# unable to display more than one dropdown menu in wordpress ajaira theme

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

I am using ajaira theme for a simple wordpress website.

I am unable to add more than one active dropdown menu to the navigation bar at the top of the homepage.

Every time I knock up a new menu it seems to kick out the existing menu

Perhaps the issue exists because I can select only one Primary menu when making up the menu ?

The theme tells me that supports 3 menus - but that will refer to 3 menu locations across the page ( header footer etc )  not just limiting me to 3 menus in the navigation bar surely ?

Very green when it comes to coding but i will have a bash !

Any tips/pointers/suggestions would be welcome... thanks.

Comment: Link of the site?

Comment: Hello, www.louisawade.co.uk. There is a menu ' family law ' there right now. Thanks.

Comment: You may need to edit header.php to include option for two menus in primary position .

Comment: Ok thanks. I worked out how to have one or more drop down menus without  changing code. It seems that when creating a menu you create & name your menu, then assign placeholders if required, then have all your pages within the menu and then drag the pages underneath the appropriate placeholders finally assigning as primary menu.